# i18n React-Native unexpected token ';'

Tags: react-native

I have I18n set up in an IOS project and am working in an Android project now.

I keep getting an unexpected token ';' error.

When I comment out the import statement for strings and the static navigationOptions the error goes away and the build succeeds:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackgroud,
  // TextInput
} from 'react-native';
// import {
//   Button
// } from 'react-native-elements';
// import {
//   Spinner
// } from '../components/common';

here --> //import { strings } from '../locales/i18n';

class SignUp extends Component {

  //static navigationOptions = {
 here -->// title: strings('SignUp.title')
  //}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
   return (
      <ImageBackgroud
        source={require('.././assets/swooshResize.jpg')}
        style={styles.backG}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>
           HELLO!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackgroud>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backG: {
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%'
  },
});

export default SignUp;
```

This is the locales file i18n.js:

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import en from './en.json';
import fr from './fr.json';
import es from './es.json';

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en, 
  fr,
  es
};

// RTL language support
// export const isRTL = currentLocale.indexOf('he') === 0 || 
currentLocale.indexOf('ar') === 0;

// Allow RTL alignment in RTL languages
// ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);

export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return I18n.t(name, params);
}

export default I18n;
```

And this is the JSON for english:

```
{
  "SignUp": {
    "title": "Sign Up"
  }
}
```

Entire Error Message:

Unexpected token ';' (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta? 
   platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:112892)

Unexpected token ';' (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta? 
   platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:112892)

I had this working in an IOS build and then noticed react-native i18n updated to 2.0.15 and now I get this weird error. Any help would be greatly appreciated also I did change it to the documentation specs and it still had an error. eslint in running.

Maybe a fresh set of eyes will help.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this post

Comment: What is the exact error message and which line does it refer to? Is the first code a working version (that you have already commented out) or one that doesn't work? Is it the entire contents of the file (because it's missing the closing bracket for the class declaration)?

Comment: thanks JJJ, the class works fine when those two lines are commented out (the app build is successful) this error happens when the strings and navigationOptions are not commented out and it is imported into the SignUp class. Thank you for taking a look at this. I also added the errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. No clue where to start. Turns out that if one of your translation files is just empty (not even containing `{}`) it will throw this error.

Solved it by providing all the translation files with content, at least `{}` to make it a valid json file.

Opened [this ticket](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/issues/513).

Comment: I met this problem, and I found all my i18n json files are exited.  However I cleaned its content to {}, then restore those content, everything goes fine! wired!

Comment: That's at least the right answer. I had exactly the same issue and I spend a couple of time to figure this out. Wish I had found this answer before search & found an solution by myself. As I wan't to check if this question still exist @ stackoverflow - and if not... to create and answer it to help other ones - I found your answer. So ThumbsUp for your answer!

Comment: So great!! Thank so much! ^^